# Geocoder only returns null objects

Tags: java, android, geocoding

i am making an android app, one feature of the app is that it can geocode an inputted street address to its latitude and longitude and then mark this point on a the map.

I have tried all kinds of solutions from all over the place but i cannot get it to work!

```
  public LatLng getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress) {

    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> address;

    try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 1);
        while(address.size()==0){
            address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress,1);
        }
        Address location = address.get(0);
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        return new LatLng(lat,lng);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When i test out this method as shown below:

```
       pickupPointsPlots.add(getLocationFromAddress("london"));
        for (int i = 0; i < pickupPointsPlots.size(); i++) {
        LatLng position = pickupPointsPlots.get(i);
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(position);

        googleMap.addMarker(options);

    }

}
```

I get this error

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: latlng cannot be null - a position is required.
```

Comment: You're swallowing the exception. At the very least, print its stack trace.

Comment: BTW, the `address = ...` and while loop can be written without repeating yourself as a `do/while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try.

(Note: You made `getLocationFromAddress()` a public method so I can't be certain if this is in another class from where it is being called so I am passing the context to be certain. If the `getLocationFromAddress()` is in your activity class then just use "TheNameOfActivity.this" instead of the `getApplicationContext()`.)

```
public LatLng getLocationFromAddress(Context context, String strAddress) {
    LatLng latLng = null;
    try {
        Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 1);
        // will only iterate through address list when the geocoder was successful
        for(Address a : address){
            latLng = new LatLng(a.getLatitude, a.getLongitude);
            Log.e(TAG, "Country Name = " + a.getCountryName());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Log that error!
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    //will return null if an address was not found
    return latLng;
}
```

Your `getLocationFromAddress()` method is only returning a single location so no need for a list. So working with your code fragment:

```
    ....
    LatLng latLng = getLocationFromAddress(TheNameOfActivity.this, "london");
    if(latLng != null){
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
        if(googleMap != null){
            googleMap.addMarker(options);
        {
    }
}
```

Be certain to replace "TheNameOfActivity"  with the actual name of your activity

Comment: Still getting the same error, if i implement the second code snippet you suggested, the app does not crash, but it still does not function as it is supposed to :(
Is it possible that i need to check permissions for INTERNET or something before? I just cant wrap my head around why this is failing!

Comment: @jammymister :: I made a mistake and left `return new LatLng(lat,lng);` in my code I hope you caught that! (I should have removed it!)  Check my edit to see what I changed. Beside that my App requests `INTERNET` permission. If you are using "Google Maps Android API v2" you do not need to explicitly request `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`

Comment: @jammymister :: The only difference between the code above and the code I use in my App (which is working properly!) is I do not use   `Locale.getDefault()` to initialize my `GeoCoder` object.

Comment: @jammymister :: Are you testing on a real device?  Is the internet connection working properly?

Comment: Thanks for the help Barns!
I have been testing on a real device yup, i restarted the device as a last hope and somehow that fixed it haha!

I was using a pickupPointsList of LngLat because i am trying to read in a list of jobs from firebase and then display the pickup locations on my map!
     pickupPointsPlots.add(getLocationFromAddress(this,"london"));
works perfectly, but 
   for(Job j:Jobs){
            LatLng loca = getLocationFromAddress(this, j.getPickupLoc());
            pickupPointsPlots.add(loca);
        }
Doesn't do anything, i dont suppose you see why?
thanks again!